# MAXIFS and dynamicly generated array not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to incorporate `MAXIFS` into some of my formulas and I have noticed that it is not working well with dynamically generated arrays, e.g. using `SEQUENCE()`. However, it will work fine when the array is created in an excel cell and then is referred into the `MAXIFS` function.

You can see in this picture the `MAXIFS` (`RST`) returns a `#Value` error when the dynamic array (`S_SQ`) is created using `SEQUENCE()`, as part of the `LET` scope.

[image]

While it is working fine when the sequence is created in `A3` first as a dynamic array (`A3#`) and then taken into `S_SQ` as part of the `LET` scope.

[image]

In the second picture, `A3` has this formula `= SEQUENCE(ROWS(B3:B9))`

I have no idea why this is happening! or if I am doing something wrong. I believe `MINIFS` and `SUMIFS` have the same issue if I may say that.

Please help

Comment: for some reason, I can't get this formula `=MAXIFS( SEQUENCE(ROWS(B3:B9)), SEQUENCE(ROWS(B3:B9)), 5 )` accepted as an excel formula.

Comment: You are correct.  They will not accept an array and it must be a range.  When referring to `A3#` it is returning a range of the used spilled cells not an array, which is why it works.

Comment: `SEQUENCE(ROWS(B3:B9))` will return an array and not a range.  So it will not work in MAXIFS.

Comment: Instead switch to `MAX(FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(B3:B9)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(B3:B9))= 5 ))`

Comment: I was not aware of that, I thought it is supported... is there a similar function that can support it? The multiple criteria of MAXIFS really help speed up the process in case of a large amount of data and I want to avoid using cells.

Comment: I think I can use your formula, but is there a way to replace `5` with multiple values so that we have multiple results. `MAXIFS` was really helpful in that matter. I mean I would do something like that `=MAXIFS(A3#, A3#, "=" & J3:J5)` where J3:J5 is the replaced value of `5` and `A3#` is the sequence that I want to dynamically create.

Comment: Just use FILTER: `=FiLTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(B3:B9)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(SEQUENCE(ROWS(B3:B9)),J3:J5,0)))`

Comment: I really appreciate your help... but what if I want to use `"<" & J3:J5`

Comment: we have now gotten way past this question.  Please create a new question that specifically addresses what you want to do with your data.  Please include mock data and expected outcome.  This question was about why arrays do not work and ranges do.  Ask a new one to find out how to do what you want with your specific situation.

Comment: I have been thinking to use `= BYROW(J3:J5, LAMBDA(array,  MAX(FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(B3:B9)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(B3:B9)) < array ))))`, is tehre an alternative but faster way